# How to check presence of static const member with SFINAE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfinae

Suppose i have several structs with fields that are optional:

```
struct Param1
{
    static const bool x = true;
};

struct Param2
{
};
```

And want to write template function

```
template <class ParamType>
bool ReturnParam();
```

Which should return `ParamType::x` if static field `x` exists, otherwise it should return `false`

I suppose that some SFINAE magic should help.

#### Constraint

I am using MSVC 2010, so I cannot use most of C++11 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly:

```
template<typename T, typename MemberPtrGetter>
struct has_member_impl
{
private:
    template<typename U> static char Test(typename MemberPtrGetter::template type<U>*);
    template<typename U> static int Test(...);

public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};


template <typename T, typename MemberPtrGetter>
struct has_member: public std::integral_constant<bool, has_member_impl<T, MemberPtrGetter>::value>
{
};

struct StaticMemberGetter
{
    template <typename T, const bool = T::x>
    struct type
    {
    };
};

struct Param1
{
    static const bool x = true;
};

struct Param2
{
};

template <typename Param, typename T = void> 
struct ExtractParam
{
    static const bool x = false;
};

template <typename Param>
struct ExtractParam<Param, std::true_type>
{
    static const bool x = Param::x;
};

template <typename Param>
bool ReturnParam()
{
    return ExtractParam<Param, has_member<Param, StaticMemberGetter>>::x;
}
```

Comment: Your code should also accept non-const bool, thing convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @Jarod42 No, it should not :) Because i need `x` to be compile time constant for another reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following traits:

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static char check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);                   \
        template<typename T> static int check(...);                         \
    public:                                                                 \
        enum { value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(char)};                \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_x, T::x, const bool *);
```

Then SFINAE or tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_x<T>::value, bool>::type
ReturnParam()
{
    return T::x;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!has_x<T>::value, bool>::type
ReturnParam()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot helps with `static const bool x`
Compiler reject code with error `cannot take & on constant` or smth like this. I found a solution, see my answer